# How to open a second instance of the pdf x-change viewer?

Tags: windows-xp, pdf

Every time I open a new document in the pdf x-change viewer, it gets opened in the same window. I want to place different documents on different places on the screen (independently of each other, not just tiling the window for side-by-side view), but cannot do it. Even going to the start menu and starting the reader again doesn't open a new instance of the application. Can I force the program to open a new instance or a new independent window?

If this is impossible, which other free reader does what I need and also lets me make changes to the file? I don't need to edit the text itself, but I want to be able to add comments, underline and highlight text, and add some graphic elements (e.g. a circle or a freehand line).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to **Edit | Preference**s or press **CTRL+K**. In **General Options** check the **Allow Multiple Instances** box.

[image: Allow Multiple Instances]

Comment: Thank you, don't know how I missed it there. *throwing ash on my head*. Vote up + accept for you.

Answer (score 1):

We have tested this on Windows 7, and found that if you leave checked marked "Tabbed Documents" and "Show Close Button for each Tab". PDF Xchange Viewer Version 2.5 (Build199) it will still open each document in a Tabbed window. You have to un-check "Show Close Button for each Tab" and " Tabbed Document". This will allow you to open multiple windows.